# Metarefresh is failing when Youtube iOS app is installed

Tags: ios, http, caching, youtube, safari

Why is one metarefresh to YouTube failing while another is succeeding? And why does it have anything to do with whether Youtube as an app is installed?

We have two metarefresh links that take users to videos from an iOS app.

(1) This page refers properly to Youtube whether the Youtube iOS app is on your device or not:

The invoking link is: [http://ourURL/videos/ourpage.html](http://athla.com/videos/baseball_setup.html)

The receiving HTML page is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://youtu.be/tJ08IHetnbU" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

(2) The referral page that breaks is designed the same way but works *only* if the Youtube app is NOT on your iOS device. If the Youtube app is on your device, we see "Playback error. Tap to retry." "Error loading Tap to retry"

The invoking link is: http://ourURL.com/videos/ourpage2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://youtu.be/0FZbh-Cqfg4" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a caching issue in the YouTube app.

It appears the Youtube app relies on the Safari cache. The Meta-refresh had referred to different video links before - so the new updated links failed.

Interestingly, for whatever reason, Safari is not using its cache and showed the proper video.

After going to Settings, Safari and "Clear cookies and data" - the YouTube App started showing the referral pages properly again.